# Is it better to compress all data or compressed directories?

Tags: compression, zip, tar, archiving, rar

I'm archiving some projects, let's say each of them has own directory:

```
projects
 |- project-1
 |- project-2
 |- project-3
```

I started compressing them as following:

```
==== SITUATION 1 ====

projects
 |- project-1.zip
 |- project-2.zip
 |- project-3.zip
```

and then I started wondering if wouldn't it be better to compress all data in one zip file:

```
==== SITUATION 2 ====

projects.zip
 |- project-1
 |- project-2
 |- project-3
```

or maybe compress already compressed files?:

```
==== SITUATION 3 ====

projects.zip
 |- project-1.zip
 |- project-2.zip
 |- project-3.zip
```

Which situation is the best (occupies the least space)? Why? Does it depend on compression algorithm? I know that compressing *one* compressed file cannot help much, but let's say 20 of them? For me situation 1 doesn't look like a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that the different schemes would make a lot of difference to be honest since the compression algorithms typically only look forward a limited amount in order to control memory use.

The exception is S3 which would end up larger most likely since compressing a compressed file adds overheads but cannot compress.

If you want better compression, look for newer archiving tools that have better algorithms. 7-zip for example is generally better than zip.

In terms of the difference between s1 and s2, I would say that it depends on how you are most likely to use the archive in the future and how big they end up.

Really big archives are a pain to handle (moving, opening, etc) and this is likely to be more important than saving a few kB.

Additionally, when thinking of long-term storage, don't ignore "bit-rot". A small error in a large archive can be devastating. Loosing one project is probably much better than loosing them all.

You might however look at something like RAR which allows redundancy and split archives. This is a bit like RAID5. You create multiple archive files each of which has built in redundancy so that you can loose a file and still recreate the original data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, keep the excellent arguments of @Julian Knight in mind. Even the best compression is useless if your archive is either too big to handle or gets corrupted by some flipped bits.

If space is your main concern, it might be worthwhile to do some experiments with your particular data and different compression algorithms.

Also, your 3rd approach can indeed lead to another reduction in size. I remember some discussion ([see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lz4c/DcN5SgFywwk/AVMOPri0O3gJ)) about compressing files multiple times using different algorithms. The author was compressing highly redundant text files and could go from 100GB to a few MB after experimenting enough. Note that his case was a bit special, but the general idea is that iterated compression can actually be worthwhile in some cases.

If you are willing to try different compression algorithms, here are some benchmarks that compare speed and compression ratio:

- http://catchchallenger.first-world.info//wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO
- http://binfalse.de/2011/04/04/comparison-of-compression

Answer (score 0):

Situation 3 is out because it's pointless re-compressing archives with the same algorithm.

Between Situations 1 and 2 the latter definitely has more chance of resulting in a smaller archive, especially when you use larger dictionary sizes (the dictionary in simple words is the memory area used to find and compress repeated patterns in data). Plain old ZIP can only use a tiny 32KB dictionary, which given the hardware these days is way too small.

The RAR 5.0 format by comparison can use a 1GB dictionary on 64-bit systems. It also supports *saving identical files as references*:

> If this option is enabled, WinRAR analyzes the file contents before
>   starting archiving. If several identical files larger than 64 KB are
>   found, the first file in the set is saved as usual file and all
>   following files are saved as references to this first file. It allows
>   to reduce the archive size, but applies some restrictions to resulting
>   archive. You must not delete or rename the first identical file in
>   archive after the archive was created, because it will make extraction
>   of following files using it as a reference impossible. If you modify
>   the first file, following files will also have the modified contents
>   after extracting. Extraction command must involve the first file to
>   create following files successfully.

Thus if you have many duplicate files among your projects, a large dictionary size combined with solid archiving and the feature above is very likely to lead to significant size reduction with **Situation 2**. Of course all the general caveats about large archives apply, so including a *recovery record* would also be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, Situation 3 is the worst of all. The first two options are roughly the same, but Situation 2 is slightly better because of some metadata (and possibly dictionary) reuse

However for archiving purposes all the above are not good because zip format doesn't support [solid archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression). 7z and rar do use solid archives by default ([Do 7z archives compress each file individually or compress everything together as one?](https://superuser.com/q/1431995/241386)) so the compression ratio is much better (because you most definitely have the same byte patterns repeated in many files). It's the same way you `tar` (i.e. making a solid uncompressed archive) then pass to gz or bz2 to compress. OTOH zip compresses each file separately so it'll be easier to extract separate files but the compressed output would be much larger

So you should use Situation 2 but change to 7z or rar